# On the SDL Tridion 2011 GA Publishing Queue, is it possible to default "user" to the active logged in?

Tags: tridion

Every time I want to use the Publishing Queue, I have to change User to myself then show the tasks. Tridion knows who I am, so why can't the form automatically display with my name selected?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a defect in SDL Tridion 2011 GA (I believe it worked in most versions of R5 and Tridion 2009). It is fixed in SDL Tridion 2011 SP1, so you best bet is to upgrade to the latest release.

Comment: Bummer. I was kind of afraid someone would say that. We recently lost the person who was the great wizard for Tridion, so I'm not looking forward to asking about upgrading.

Comment: It is indeed the case, I can confirm that in SP1 it defaults to the current user. You should really look at updating to SP1, most of the nice stuff coming up will require SP1 as a start (especially the new UI)

Comment: Regardless of in-house resources, you _still_ need to ask IT ops for upgrades. No begging for forgiveness there! Tip: find and share the compelling upgrade reasons; it's not asking, it's selling. Service Packs are a good thing, right?